# How do I synchronize RabbitMQ .erlang.cookie with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, erlang, rabbitmq, erlang-otp

I am trying to syncrhonize the .erlang.cookie with:

```
copy /y "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.erlang.cookie" "%USERPROFILE%"
```

and I am getting

> Access Denied.

I really want to be able to set up a server completely without user intervention.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the source (...\.erlang.cookie) a directory or a file?  Does it exist?  Seems like an odd place for a non-system file.

Comment: you need to run the cmd as administrator.

Comment: @jwdonahue `access denied` is a different error from `file not found` it simply needs admin rights to copy to `%userprofile%`.

Comment: @jwdonahue yes it exists. https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I am running cmd as an administrator.

Comment: By actually right clicking and selecting run as admin?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yessir. Doing  `copy /y "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.erlang.cookie" "%USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP"` works. I just can't copy it into the %USERPROFILE% root folder. UAC is off.

Comment: Admin has all rights it must. Is you environment still fine?

Comment: Yeah, I mean I'm doing dev on a brand new Surface Book 2, local Admin account.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. `%USERPROFILE%\.erlang.cookie` is set to read only.

I was as able to remove that in a non elevated CMD with:

`atrrib -r -s "%userprofile%\.erlang.cookie"`

and then the copy worked fine...

`copy /y "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.erlang.cookie" "%USERPROFILE%"`